# Launch Screen image only showing on iPhone 4s, 5s, and 6s

Tags: ios, xcode, launchimage

For some reason, as the title states, the launch screen image only seems to be working on the iPhone 4s, 5s, 6s (But not the 6s Plus) for some reason.  Otherwise the screen would just be blank. At first, I thought that it could've been a resolution problem.  As far as I know, the 5s and 5 both have the same resolution, so I really can't pinpoint a problem.

**Here are some things that I've tried**

- Adding all device resolutions to the launch image asset folder (Including iPads)
- Left the "Launch Screen File" field blank
- Double checked the resolutions of all the pictures being used for the launch screens

In the launch image assets folder I'm using the current resolutions, all with their proper resolutions.

- iPhone Portrait iOS 8,9

  - Retina HD 5.5
  - Retina HD 4.7
- iPhone Portrait iOS 7-9

  - Retina 4
  - 2x

All portraits of course, the application will not be using the landscape view.

Thanks for any help, ask me if you need anymore information.

Comment: I have situation with only iphone s4 launch image not working ...